# Post a copy of a single worksheet into Microsoft Teams

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-teams

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets, and I want to copy one of those worksheets and paste it into the chat of Microsoft Teams. Is it possible to do with a VBA macro? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to copy total worksheet to teams chat? How did you paste the worksheet to teams chat using graph API? Could you please explain your scenario in detail?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT If I have to do it manually I would save a copy of the worksheet in any location in my computer, then I would open Teams with the shortcut I have in my taskbar, look for the particular chat and drag and copy the excel file. Then I would proceed to delete the copy of the worksheet in my computer.

Comment: Are you pasting it manually?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Right now, yes. I'm hoping to automate it, thus the question here.

Comment: Are you trying to copy on 1:1 chat or in channel?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT No, it is a 'team channel'.

Comment: You can use [Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to send a message to channel. Could you please go through the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Try if that helps